# Windows authentication in android

Tags: android

I am using WCF webservice in android... i've to authenticate the user with windows authentication
Here's my java code

```
public void test3()
{
       try
       {
               DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
               URI uri = new URI("http://10.0.2.2/MicrosoftDynamicsAXAif60/testgroup/xppservice.svc"); 

                       // Send GET request to <service>/GetText
                       HttpPost httpget = new HttpPost(uri);
                       StringEntity se = null;

                        // declare it as XML
                       se = new StringEntity(this.returnXML(), HTTP.UTF_8);

                       se.setContentType("text/xml");
                       httpget.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml;charset=UTF-8");
                       httpget.setEntity(se);

                       //NTCredentials nt = new NTCredentials("username", "pass", "", "domain");
                       httpClient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, nt);


                       HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpget);
                       HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();

                       // Read response data into buffer
                       long intCount = responseEntity.getContentLength();
               char[] buffer = new char[(int)intCount];
               InputStream stream = responseEntity.getContent();
               InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8");
               try
               {
                       reader.read(buffer);


                       String str = new String(buffer);
                       Toast.makeText(this, str, 10);
               }

               catch (IOException e) 
               {e.printStackTrace();}
               stream.close();


       } 
       catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}

   }
```

Now am getting HTTP Error 401.2 - Unauthorized

Here's xml config

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
      <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
          <binding name="wsHttpBindingWithWindowsAuth">
              <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
                  <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" >
                      <extendedProtectionPolicy protectionScenario="TransportSelected" policyEnforcement="Always" />
                  </transport>
                  <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
              </security>
          </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
          <basicHttpBinding>
              <binding name="basicHttpBindingWithWindowsAuth">
                  <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
                      <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
                  </security>
              </binding>
          </basicHttpBinding>
          <netTcpBinding>
          <binding name="DefaultServiceGroupBinding" closeTimeout="00:05:00" openTimeout="00:05:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:05:00" transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="10" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxBufferSize="81920000" maxConnections="10" maxReceivedMessageSize="81920000">
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="32000000" maxStringContentLength="81920000" maxArrayLength="163840000" maxBytesPerRead="4096000" maxNameTableCharCount="16384000" />
            <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" enabled="false" />
            <security mode="Transport">
              <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
              <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
            </security>
          </binding>
        </netTcpBinding>
      </bindings>

      <services>
        <!--ROUTING SERVICE -->
        <!--Define a routing service.  The Behavior Configuration field references the name of the Routing Behavior that this service will use-->
        <service name="System.ServiceModel.Routing.RoutingService" behaviorConfiguration="routingData">
          <!--
            Define and configure the endpoint we want the Router to listen on and the Contract we want it to use
            Router provided contracts are:  ISimplexDatagramRouter, ISimplexSessionRouter, IRequestReplyRouter, and IDuplexSessionRouter.          
           -->
          <endpoint address=""
                    binding="basicHttpBinding"
                    bindingConfiguration="basicHttpBindingWithWindowsAuth"
                    name="reqReplyEndpoint"
                    contract="System.ServiceModel.Routing.IRequestReplyRouter" >
            <identity>
              <servicePrincipalName />
            </identity>
          </endpoint>
        </service>
      </services>

      <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
          <behavior name="routingData">
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="false" />
            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
            <!--
            Define the Routing Behavior.  The routingTableName attribute contains the name of the Routing Table that this behavior will use.          
            <routing filterTableName="AosRoutingTable" />
            -->
          </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>

        <endpointBehaviors>
          <behavior name="clientEndpointBehavior">
            <clientEndpointBehavior />
          </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
      </behaviors>

      <extensions>
        <behaviorExtensions>
          <add
              name="clientEndpointBehavior"
              type="Microsoft.Dynamics.Ax.Services.Host.ClientEndpointBehaviorExtension, Microsoft.Dynamics.IntegrationFramework.WebService.Process, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"   />
        </behaviorExtensions>
      </extensions>

      <!--
        Define the client endpoints that we want the Router to communicate with.  These are the destinations that the Router will send messages to.
        Note that we always define the client endpoint contract as *.  The router will mirror the selected contract defied on the endpoint 
        on which the message was originally recieved.
      -->
      <client>
                  <endpoint name="ServiceCustom" address="net.tcp://AOS_SERVICE_HOST/DynamicsAx/Services/testgroup" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="DefaultServiceGroupBinding" contract="*" behaviorConfiguration="clientEndpointBehavior">
              <identity><servicePrincipalName /></identity>
          </endpoint>    

      </client>
        <routing>
            <!--
          Define the filters that we want the router to use.  In this example we define a MatchAll message filter, which will match all messages it sees.
        -->
            <filters>
                        <filter name="MatchServiceCustom" filterType="Custom" customType="Microsoft.Dynamics.Ax.Services.Host.MatchAxServiceFilter, Microsoft.Dynamics.IntegrationFramework.WebService.Process" filterData="http://tempuri.org/ServiceCustom" />

            </filters>

            <!-- Define the routing table that contains the matchAll filter defined in the filters section. -->
            <filterTables>
                <filterTable name="AosRoutingTable">
                    <!-- Map the filter to a client endpoint that was previously defined. Messages that match this filter will be sent to this destination. -->
                            <add filterName="MatchServiceCustom" endpointName="ServiceCustom" />

                </filterTable>
            </filterTables>
        </routing>
    </system.serviceModel>
  </configuration>
```

The xml that i am sending

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
<s:Header>
<a:Action>http://tempuri.org/ServiceCustom/CreateMyDataObject</a:Action>
<h:CallContext i:nil="true" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:h="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2010/01/datacontracts" />
<a:MessageID>urn:uuid:c70fb5f6-1345-469d-84fd-bb24500d329a</a:MessageID>
<a:ReplyTo>
  <a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>
</a:ReplyTo>
</s:Header>
<s:Body>
<ServiceCustomCreateMyDataObjectRequest xmlns="http://tempuri.org">
<_s>23</_s>
</ServiceCustomCreateMyDataObjectRequest>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

**Solved!**

> http://mrrask.wordpress.com/2009/08/21/android-authenticating-via-ntlm/

Answer (score 0):

(The OP answered by posting a web link. Converted to a Community Wiki Answer; [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The link was: http://mrrask.wordpress.com/2009/08/21/android-authenticating-via-ntlm/

A summary of which is:

> It uses an HttpClient which needs an AuthScemeFactory that will return the AuthScheme descendant NTLMScheme. NTLMScheme requires an implementation of the NTLMEngine interface to operate on. The JCIFS library has functionality for creating type 1 2 & 3 NTLM messages making it a perfect candidate for implementing the NTLMEngine.