# User Windows desktop login as user authentication in Android app

Tags: android, windows-authentication

just wondering if there is a way to authenticate users with their windows desktop credentials? I'm trying to allow users to access the app with their windows credentials.

Any idea on this will be greatly helpful.

TIA!

Comment: Do you mean NTLM? http://stackoverflow.com/q/32435086/11683, http://stackoverflow.com/q/7915148/11683

Comment: Hi @GSerg thanks for the links. could you pls tell whether those mentioned authentication mechanism allows user to login with their windows credentials? Bcos the ultimate aim is this - authenticate user with their currently used windows credentials.