# Android App to query WebAPI with Windows Authentication

Tags: android, authentication, asp.net-web-api, design-patterns, architecture

For the last few years I have been working on a fairly comprehensive Intranet for the company I work for.  I use Visual Studio, C#, MVC and Entity Framework and the whole thing is secured with Windows Authentication which is supplied by the user's PC when they are in the office, or explicity via a login box if they want to access the Intranet from home.

Recently I've been asked to consider writing a mobile app which excites me and terrifies me at the same time.  What I would like to know is the best way of accomplishing this using as much of my existing code and as much of my existing skillset as possible.

This is what I think I need to do - is this the right way to go/will it work?

1. Write a WebAPI which accepts Windows Credentials and returns data to external users
2. Use Xamarin Forms to create a mobile front end
3. Require the user to enter their Windows Credentials on first use
4. Use these credentials to query our internal databases through the API

If someone can suggest a better way, please do, but my real concern is that I should be using a different system of authentication.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Matt

Comment: Possible duplicate :
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7915148/windows-authentication-in-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7915148/windows-authentication-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

You should also consider using Retrofit library for Web requests.